# Oracle Update Column LTRIM and RTRIM

Tags: sql, oracle

I am wish to update my database data in SQL Developer using

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN_NAME = LTRIM(RTRIM(COLUMN_NAME))
```

But it does not take any effect even the msg of "rows updated" is displayed. The leading and trailing white spaces still exist behind every strings.

Any ideas?

Comment: By default, `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` don't remove whitespace in general, but the space character specifically (ASCII 32, U+0020). That is, `RTRIM(column_name)` is equivalent to `RTRIM(column_name, ' ')`. Are you sure that your leading and trailing whitespace consists of the space character?

Comment: Have you tried to query for potentially changing rows, i.e. run `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME <> LTRIM(RTRIM(COLUMN_NAME))`

Comment: 1, You don't need to use ltrim and rtrim instead, simply use trim(column_name),

Answer (score 11):

Do you commit after update?

```
update tableName set col1 = trim(col1);
commit;
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on two different tables. One the first table trim was ok, on the second no effect, the spaces were still there!

The difference was that in the first table I was using `varchar2(30)` and in the second table (where trim didn't work) I had `char(30)`

After modifying the second table from `char(30)` to `varchar2(30)` trim worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN_NAME = TRIM(COLUMN_NAME);
```

[Trim Reference](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trim.php)

Comment: While it's simpler code, this does nothing to solve the OP's actual problem. Unless you know something we don't - in which case, please expand your answer to say why.

Comment: your query won't make any affect with the question!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `REGEXP_REPLACE(your column name, '\s*', '')` ?

ex:  `UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN_NAME = REGEXP_REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, '\s*', '')`

Answer (score 0):

You get a message saying that n rows are updated because there are n rows in your table and you are applying the update to all of them.

To limit the update to only those rows where the update will have an effect, use:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET    COLUMN_NAME = LTRIM(RTRIM(COLUMN_NAME))
WHERE  COLUMN_NAME != LTRIM(RTRIM(COLUMN_NAME));
```